# Twilio Autopilot with Whatsapp wrong message order

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-functions

I am using Twilio Autopilot + Functions to build a chat bot. If I use Whatsapp i have an issue with the order of my messages if I send a URL. I assume this is because Whatsapp is processing the URL, which takes more time than the next message. I tried to build in a delay but than the two message i send arrives after the delay together and in a wrong order.
Any idea how to send two message separately and give time for WA to process the URL?
This is my code:

Funcation 1 response:

```
responseObject = {
      "actions": [
        {
          "say": `Please find information about ${shareLink}`
        },
        {
          "redirect": "task://anything_else"
        }
      ]
    };
return callback(null, responseObject);
```

Function 2 (redirect from Function 1 points here via Autopilot) (task://anything_else)

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {

    let delayInMs = 5000;

    let respsoneObject = {
        "actions": [
            {
                "collect": {
                    "name": "anything_else",
                    "questions": [
                        {
                            "question": "Can I help you with anything else?",
                            "name": "need_help",
                            "type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
                        }
                    ],
                    "on_complete": {
                        "redirect": "task://goodbye"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    let timerUp = () => {
        return callback(null, respsoneObject);
    };

    setTimeout(timerUp, delayInMs);
};
```

My problem is that the "Can I help you with anything else?" question appears before the message which shares more information. However i would expect the link first.

I also tried to merge the two messages in the same response by adding say and collect to the action array, the result is the same.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: WhatsApp doesn't guarantee the message order, so it's always a hit or miss. Usually your approach with two different functions works, if it's only text messages. I ran into the same problem with attached media which always need some time to appear. So the only answer is to experiment... have you thought about moving the question into the `say`, i.e. `Please find information about ${shareLink}. Can I help you with anything else?` And then leaving the `"question" : ""` empty? If I remember correctly empty messages are not displayed by WhatsApp.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Eventually i ended up in the same conclusion and added the question to the end of my messages.